# While trying to add the value i.e. American express to the vendor field, the code is not working

Tags: c#, .net, netsuite

```
    List<ListOrRecordRef> List = new List<ListOrRecordRef>();
    ListOrRecordRef RecordRefItem = new ListOrRecordRef();
    RecordRefItem.name = "American Express";
    RecordRefItem.internalId = "898";
    RecordRefItem.typeId = "394";
    List.Add(RecordRefItem);
    rec.customFieldList = List.ToArray();

    WriteResponse response = service.add(rec);
```

The code is used to add multiselect option of vendor. ex : american express

Comment: Could you rephrase the question header by removing the tags? And please explain the problem in some detail and what did you try, error message, etc. So that others can help you.

Comment: I don't think you can use keyword (e.g. "List") as a parameter name.

Comment: I have rephrased the question,please have a look,as it is a select type field value, simple way to add is not working.

Comment: i am taking list as the option is select drop down list and simple way for adding of free form like CustomFieldRef.scriptId and CustomFieldRef.value is not working

Comment: Error message? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

First of all like  Heinz Siahaan said: 'List' is a keyword in C# so you can't create variable with this name.

Second:

```
ListOrRecordRef RecordRefItem = new ListOrRecordRef();
```

I'm not sure but name of this method suggest that this line of code creates list of records not one item so you can't use something like this:

```
RecordRefItem.name = "American Express";
```

but you should try :

```
RecordRefItem[i].name = "American Express";
```

where i is and index of element, but before access it you must create it

Comment: I tried the above two modification but its not working error given for when we change the name of list to list1 is:cannot implicitly convert type &

Comment: RecordRefItem[i].name = "American Express"; for these change error is cannot apply indexing

Comment: Check if this code: ListOrRecordRef RecordRefItem = new ListOrRecordRef(); creates list or one item?

Comment: As per i checked: ListOrRecordRef RecordRefItem = new ListOrRecordRef() , it will create an item whereas ListOrRecordRef[] RecordRefItem = new ListOrRecordRef[2](), will create a list.

Comment: Ok, so if you do this part of code: 
`List<ListOrRecordRef> list1= new List<ListOrRecordRef>();
    ListOrRecordRef RecordRefItem = new ListOrRecordRef();
    RecordRefItem.name = "American Express";
    RecordRefItem.internalId = "898";
    RecordRefItem.typeId = "394";
    List.Add(RecordRefItem);`

It still doesn't work? And if it doesn't work is there any error message?

Comment: The above block of code works fine, but when i do it, it comes error,:rec.customFieldList = List1.ToArray(); //connot convet type

Comment: So its mean that `rec.customFieldList` is different type than ListOrRecordRef[]

Answer (score 0):

found a way its working fine://Note that for multi select option to set we have to take two class:ListOrRecordRef mention the id of the 898:American express&
            //SelectCustomFieldRef to mention the field
            ListOrRecordRef recordRefItem = new ListOrRecordRef();
            recordRefItem.internalId = "898";
            SelectCustomFieldRef scfr = new SelectCustomFieldRef();
            scfr.scriptId = "custrecord_from_so_customer";
            scfr.value = recordRefItem;//set the object value to the mentioned field
            customFieldArray[1] = scfr;
rec.customFieldList = customFieldArray